# Eloquent - What is $fillable really for?

Tags: php, laravel

This is what Laravel document sais :

> To get started, you should define which model attributes you want to
>   make mass assignable. You may do this using the $fillable property on
>   the model

So why not just let all the attributes to be assigned by the ->fill()/::create() methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Software frameworks sometime allow developers to automatically bind HTTP request parameters into program code variables or objects to make using that framework easier on developers. This can sometimes cause harm.

Attackers can sometimes use this methodology to create new parameters that the developer never intended which in turn creates or overwrites new variable or objects in program code that was not intended.

This is called a **Mass Assignment vulnerability**.

And laravel provider [fillable for mass-assignment vulnerability](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment), it is a white-list for fields.

> A mass-assignment vulnerability occurs when a user passes an unexpected HTTP parameter through a request, and that parameter changes a column in your database you did not expect. For example, a malicious user might send an is_admin parameter through an HTTP request, which is then passed into your model's create method, allowing the user to escalate themselves to an administrator.

Comment: You could argue that you don't even need to set `$fillable`, if you were to use Form request validation, the `$request->validated()` data will only return the data that you *specifically* validated for. Meaning it will throw away and ignore any potential malcious inputs made by the user. Adding to `$fillable` and `$guarded` restricts your database layer, and can cause extra complications if you want to modify a `$guarded` field as an admin later on.

Answer (score 5):

Good question! This may shed some light:

To make it easy to store / update data from a form Laravel lets you perform `User::update($request->all());`

Now picture me as an evil user: I tamper with the Form and add the following field: `['role' => 'supermegaadmin']` you will store it in the database and I will get a role I'm not supposed to get (This is an over-simplistic scenario, but should help you get the point)

You can then use `$fillable` and `$guarded` to have a finer control over the fields that can be mass-assigned.

Comment: Thank You. One vote up for your help. But there is no $protected. There is $guarded

Comment: Ooh my bad fixed

Comment: `User::update($request->all())` Who would do this evil line?

Answer (score 2):

It's important to always add the attributes *you want to be able to edit* to the **$fillable** array. You will need to specify either a **fillable** or **guarded** attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.
So, what is mass-assignment? According to Laravel document:

> A mass-assignment vulnerability occurs when a user passes an
>   unexpected HTTP parameter through a request, and that parameter
>   changes a column in your database you did not expect. For example, a
>   malicious user might send an is_admin parameter through an HTTP
>   request, which is then passed into your model's create method,
>   allowing the user to escalate themselves to an administrator.

Comment: merC dooste aziz.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, `$fillable` is more secure as it uses a whitelist approach while `guarded` uses a blacklist approach. The difference is that a whitelist approach ensures that only the explicitly allowed attributes can be updated, while a blacklist approach might not block all unwanted changes.